# Concatenate filename with current directory path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell script that opens an Excel file and does a SaveAs with it. the problem is that it works when I put the full path for the file, but I want it to be directed to the working folder, that way if I take the script and files to other location I don't have to modify the script for each environment.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("E:\TEMP\TEMPLATE4WEEKS.xlsx")#Opening like this works

$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TEMPLATE4WEEKS.xlsx") #this is not working 
$wb.SaveAs(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TEMPLATE4WEEKSprotected.xlsx",[Type]::Missing,"password") #this is not working
$excel.Quit()
```

I was trying to concatenate current folder so it will work if I say move the entire folder to another path.

Right now the folder that contains the PS1 script is the same that contains the TEMPLATE4WEEKS.xlsx file. I want all to operate inside the same folder.

Changed as per Ansgar's response:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$file = Join-Path $excel.ThisWorkbook.Path "TEMPLATE4WEEKS.xlsx"
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$wb.SaveAs($file,[Type]::Missing,"password")
$excel.Quit()
```

I'm getting this error now:

```
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\AGUIRRG2\Desktop\Newfolder\PasswordProtect4WEEKSCopy.ps1:4 char:19
+ $file = Join-Path $excel.ThisWorkbook.Path "TEMPLATE4WEEKS.xlsx"
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path],     ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Sorry, we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
At C:\Users\AGUIRRG2\Desktop\Newfolder\PasswordProtect4WEEKSCopy.ps1:5 char:1
+ $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\AGUIRRG2\Desktop\Newfolder\PasswordProtect4WEEKSCopy.ps1:6 char:1
+         $wb.SaveAs($file,[Type]::Missing,"password")
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Path doesn't exists in your context. You should use wb.Path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a relative path instead of a physical one, use the variable `$pwd`. It's your current working directory:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$LoadPath = Join-Path -Path $pwd -ChildPath "TEMPLATE4WEEKS.xlsx"    #$pwd is your current working dir
$SavePath = Join-Path -Path $pwd -ChildPath "TEMPLATE4WEEKSprotected.xlsx"
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($LoadPath)


$wb.SaveAs($SavePath,[Type]::Missing,"password")
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Note that `$pwd` is the current working directory, which is not necessarily identical with the location of the script.

Answer (score 6):

`&` in PowerShell is not a concatenation operator. Plus, you don't want to build paths via string concatenation in the first place. You also cannot use the object `ThisWorkbook` directly in PowerShell (that only works in VBA, and it's the location of the current macro, so it won't work here at all because you're not running a macro).

Change this:

```
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TEMPLATE4WEEKSxlsx")
```

into this:

```
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("${PSScriptRoot}\TEMPLATE4WEEKS.xlsx")
```

**Note:** The automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot` was introduced with PowerShell v3 and doesn't exist in earlier versions. If you're running an older version you need to define it yourself, e.g. like this:

```
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
```